# Swift Combine: Cannot refactor repetitive code

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, combine

My API returns this format, where `data` can contain all kinds of responses.

```
{
    status: // http status
    error?: // error handle
    data?:  // your response data
    meta?:  // meta data, eg. pagination
    debug?: // debuging infos
}
```

I have made a `Codable` Response type with a generic for the optional data, of which we do not know the type.

```
struct MyResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let error: String?
    let data:  T?
    let meta: Paging?
    let debug: String?
}
```

I am now trying to write API convenience methods **as concisely as possible**. So I have a function to return a generic publisher that I can use for all these responses, i.e. one that pre-parses the response and catches any errors upfront.

First, I get a `dataTaskPublisher` that processes the parameter inputs, if any. `Endpoint` is just a convenience `String` `enum` for my endpoints, `Method` is similar. `MyRequest` returns a `URLRequest` with some necessary headers etc.

Notice the way I define the parameters: `params: [String:T]`. This is standard JSON so it could be strings, numbers etc.
**It seems this `T` is the problem somehow.**.

```
static fileprivate func publisher<T: Encodable>(
        _ path: Endpoint,
        method: Method,
        params: [String:T] = [:]) throws
        -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
    {
        let url = API.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path.rawValue)
        var request = API.MyRequest(url: url)
        if method == .POST && params.count > 0 {
            request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
            do {
                let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(params)
                request.httpBody = data
                return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            }
            catch let err {
                throw MyError.encoding(description: String(describing: err))
            }
        }
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    }
```

Next, I am parsing the response.

```
static func myPublisher<T: Encodable, R: Decodable>(
        _ path: Endpoint,
        method: Method = .GET,
        params: [String:T] = [:])
        -> AnyPublisher<MyResponse<R>, MyError>
    {
        do {
                
            return try publisher(path, method: method, params: params)
            .map(\.data)
            .mapError { MyError.network(description: "\($0)")}
            .decode(type: MyResponse<R>.self, decoder: self.agent.decoder)
            .mapError { MyError.encoding(description: "\($0)")}             //(2)
            .tryMap {
                if $0.status > 204 {
                    throw MyError.network(description: "\($0.status): \($0.error!)")
                }
                else {
                    return $0 // returns a MyResponse
                }
            }
            .mapError { $0 as! MyError }
                                                                            //(1)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        catch let err {
            return Fail<MyResponse<R>,MyError>(error: err as? MyError ??
                MyError.undefined(description: "\(err)"))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
```

Now I can write an endpoint method easily. Here are two examples.

```
static func documents() -> AnyPublisher<[Document], MyError> {
    return myPublisher(.documents)
        .map(\.data!)
        .mapError { MyError.network(description: $0.errorDescription) }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher() as AnyPublisher<[Document], MyError>
}
```

and

```
static func user() -> AnyPublisher<User, MyError> {
    return myPublisher(.user)
        .map(\.data!)
        .mapError { MyError.network(description: $0.errorDescription) }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher() as AnyPublisher<User, MyError>
}
```

All this is working well. Please note that each time, I have to specify my exact return type twice. I think I can live with that.

I should be able to simplify this so that I do not have to repeat the same three operators (map, mapError, receive) in exactly the same way each time.

But when I insert `.map(\.data!)` at the location `//(1)` above I get the error `Generic parameter T could not be inferred.` at the location `//(2)`.

This is really confusing. Why does the generic type in the **input** parameters play any role here? This must be related to the call to the `.decode` operator just above, where the generic in question is called `R`, not `T`.

Can you explain this? How can I refactor these operators upstream?

Comment: What types could T be, and how would you deal with this JSON if you were not using Combine?

Comment: T are all the types allowed by json, but essentially `String`, `Int` and `Float`. I am dealing with it the way it is above, it works fine.

Comment: Oh I see the issue. You are just confused by the error message. Combine gives that compile error all the time! Nothing to do with _your_ generic. See my Tricks and Tips page for how to edit Combine code successfully: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html

Comment: But I cannot make it work... Why can I not filter further down into the `data` field? The input should be a `MyResponse` which has an optional `data` key path. After finishing everything (catching the error, receiving on main queue), the error is still there. What next?

Comment: Look especially at the Supply an Explicit Return Type section. But read the whole thing. Follow my technique, you’ll figure it out.

Comment: OK, thanks for now - I will report back.

Comment: Oh one more tip. Don’t call your generic placeholder type T. Give it a descriptive name. Otherwise you risk having too many Ts. So then you don’t know which is which. Here, you thought Combines T was your T. But you wouldn’t have thought that if your type was called UnknownType or something.

Comment: Good point this last one. Crossed my mind as well. I now analysed it according to your great page. When inspecting the input to my `map` statement (via "Show Quick Help"), it says `<<error type>>`. Going upstream, all is `<<error type>>`. Never seen this before.

Comment: Solved. But there is still some mystery... Of course, I had to change the return type from `MyResponse<R>` to `R`. After the decoding succeeds, I call `tryMap` to catch any errors **but the expected return type of that closure was now `R`, not `MyResponse<R>`.** I did not expect this. Why? Am I missing something about `tryMap`? Even if I declare the return type, it insists ("incompatible with contextual type" error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has a number of small problems. You're right that one is `[String: T]`. That means that for a given set of parameters, all the values must be of the same type. That's not "JSON." This will accept a `[String: String]` or a `[String: Int]`, but you can't have both Int and String values in the same dictionary if you do it this way. And it will also accept `[String: Document]`, and it doesn't seem like you really want that.

I'd recommend switching this to just Encodable, which would allow you to pass structs if that were convenient, or Dictionaries if that were convenient:

```
func publisher<Params: Encodable>(
    _ path: Endpoint,
    method: Method,
    params: Params?) throws
-> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher

func myPublisher<Params: Encodable, R: Decodable>(
    _ path: Endpoint,
    method: Method = .GET,
    params: Params?)
-> AnyPublisher<MyResponse<R>, MyError>
```

Then modify your `params.count` to check for nil instead.

Note that I didn't make `params = nil` a default parameter. That's because this would recreate a second problem you have. `T` (and Params) can't be inferred in the default case. For `= [:]`, what is `T`? Swift has to know, even though it's empty. So instead of a default, you use an overload:

```
func myPublisher<R: Decodable>(
    _ path: Endpoint,
    method: Method = .GET)
-> AnyPublisher<MyResponse<R>, MyError> {
    let params: String? = nil // This should be `Never?`, see https://twitter.com/cocoaphony/status/1184470123899478017
    return myPublisher(path, method: method, params: params)
}
```

Now, when you don't pass any parameters, Params automatically becomes String.

So now your code is fine, and you don't need the `as` at the end

```
func documents() -> AnyPublisher<[Document], MyError> {
    myPublisher(.documents)
        .map(\.data!)
        .mapError { MyError.network(description: $0.errorDescription) }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher() // <== Removed `as ...`
}
```

Now, that `.map(\.data!)` makes me sad. If you get back corrupt data from the server, the app will crash. There are lots of good reasons to crash apps; bad server data is never one of them. But fixing that isn't really related to this question (and is a little bit complicated because Failure types other than Error make things hard currently), so I'll leave it for now. My general recommendation is to use Error as your Failure type, and allow unexpected errors to just bubble up rather than wrapping them in an `.undefined` case. If you need some catch-all "other" anyway, you might as well do that with types ("is") rather than an extra enum case (which just moves the "is" to a switch). At the very least, I would move the Error->MyError mapping as late as possible, which will make handling this much easier.

One more tweak to make later things a little more general, I suspect MyResponse only needs to be Decodable, not Encodable (the rest of this works either way, but it makes it a little more flexible):

```
struct MyResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable { ... }
```

And to your original question of how to make this reusable, you can now pull out a generic function:

```
func fetch<DataType, Params>(_: DataType.Type,
                             from endpoint: Endpoint,
                             method: Method = .GET,
                             params: Params?) -> AnyPublisher<DataType, MyError>
where DataType: Decodable, Params: Encodable
{
    myPublisher(endpoint, method: method, params: params)
        .map(\.data!)
        .mapError { MyError.network(description: $0.errorDescription) }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// Overload to handle no parameters
func fetch<DataType>(_ dataType: DataType.Type,
                     from endpoint: Endpoint,
                     method: Method = .GET) -> AnyPublisher<DataType, MyError>
where DataType: Decodable
{
    fetch(dataType, from: endpoint, method: method, params: nil as String?)
}


func documents() -> AnyPublisher<[Document], MyError> {
    fetch([Document].self, from: .documents)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really good. **1.** I implemented the `Params?` suggestion, of course, that makes much more sense. **2.** I am trying to avoid the downside of `data!` by checking for `nil` first and throwing an error. **3.** I had already used an overload, for convenience if there are no params. **4.** Passing the `DataType.Type` to the function is a good idea, it makes calling the API even more concise. Quite elegant.